# Calculating date range for Oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm automating an Oracle script, which needs to select data from the first day of last month, to the first day of this month (this report is run on the second day of every month). But, no matter what combination of LAST_DAY, TRUNC, TO_CHAR, TO_DATE, ADD_MONTHS, etc have worked.

Can someone help me figure out how to automate the calculation for:

`WHERE date BETWEEN (first day of last month) AND (first day of this month)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TRUNC`:

```
WHERE date between trunc(trunc(sysdate,'MM')-1,'MM') and trunc(sysdate, 'MM');
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e24abff8366e4865ad4ae827ad0fda2d)**

```
select trunc(trunc(sysdate,'MM')-1,'MM') AS "first day of last month",
       trunc(sysdate, 'MM') AS "first day of this month"
from dual;
```

from dual

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
BETWEEN TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -2)) +1, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1)) +1, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```